# Why didn't google (and bing) blacklist my scraper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I need to scrape search engine results by specifying a search query like so: "firstName lastName linkedin". The purpose is to extract the linkedin profile URL. More often than not, this is the very first search result.

I used a simple nodeJs library and a recursive implementation (as shown below) to scrape close to a 1500 names. Also to test search engine limitations I ran 4 parallel instances, each pointing to google,bing,yahoo and duckduckgo respectively:

```
 const sec = require('search-engine-client');

const search = (i) => {
    if (i < queries.length) {
        sec.google(queries[i]).then(function(result) {
            console.log(i + " yahoo: " + result.links[0]);
            search(i + 1);
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
};
```

I have seen many posts stating google and others have a very low tolerance for web scrapers but I managed to run this successfully on all 4 search engines for close to a 1500 search queries. No proxies, user agent swapping or IP changing. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple.  You're using an npm library that wraps the search engines into a common client for your use.

Part of that common client is a set of defaults that pre-populates acceptable information (e.g. user-agent strings) such that the search engine doesn't quickly flag you as malicious.

https://gitlab.com/autokent/search-engine-client/blob/master/lib/defaults.js

It also does simple things like puts a short (default 1sec) timeout between each request, so that the search engine doesn't have rate limits tripped, etc.

It's probably not foolproof, but works for at least low volume searches (and yes, 1500 is pretty low volume for most search engines).

Comment: that makes sense. What would count as a high volume search? Also  if I swap user-agents and randomize the use of search engines between google, yahoo, bing and duckduckgo that would essentially further decrease chances of being blacklisted as well right?

Comment: As for what constitutes high volume? Bing once completely mirrored Google. When they started, instead of crawling and indexing the internet Bing cheated and simply crawled Google instead. They must have used lots of different IP addresses because Google caught them by inserting false search results and then tried searching Bing for it - and they found it: fake content that only exist on Google that does not exist on the internet. Check out Google's announcement of it: https://googleblog.blogspot.my/2011/02/microsofts-bing-uses-google-search.html

Comment: @fsociety yep, that'll help.  I can't speak to how soon a given engine will wise up to you, but you could check their APIs and TOS for some ballpark.